# Using QGIS modules in standalone application with PySide?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt, pyside

I want to make small standalone application using PySide and QGIS Python modules to display satellite images and do standard GIS operations, like creating new a shapefile and placing polygons or points inside it.

I installed QGIS 2.2 and added paths to the Python folder and the QGIS .dll's.

`PYTHONPATH`: I added ;C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2\apps\qgis\python; - path to python folder inside QGIS.

`path`: ;C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2\apps\qgis\bin; - path to .dll's like qgis_core.dll and qgis_gui.dll.

When I try to `import qgis.core`, I get following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Downlods/PyCharm_Projects/Project_1/Testing_Area.py", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sip
ImportError: No module named 'sip'
```

So, its telling me there is no 'sip'. I don't know, is there is some problem with my 'PYTHONPATH' or 'path'? Or its just will not work with PySide?

Comment: I dont know if this is important, but PyCharm also says "Some skeletons failed to generate: 4 modules failed in 1 interpreter." And it lists 4 qgis modules in details.

Answer (score 1):

As this answer states (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104268/66972):

> ...importing `qgis.core` requires the PyQt4 `sip` utility.

So unless you install PyQt **just** to support this dependency, you're probably out of luck. :(