# Replacing PyQt4 with PySide with standalone QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to develop an application using the QGIS libraries and PySide instead of PyQt4 due to more flexible licencing, I wonder if this is possible.

I downloaded PySide and replaced my references to PyQt4 in an existing program, and it throws this  error immediately:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\me\myapp\myapp.py", line 8, in <module>
    from qgis import core
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

This error does not appear when I use PyQt4 instead of PySide.

I'd like to know if I'm flogging a dead horse with this - I don't have the time or knowledge to contribute any changes to QGIS source code to accommodate PySide (if that's what it requires).

I found the only other reference to this [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101859/using-qgis-modules-in-standalone-application-with-pyside) but with no answers.

Comment: Flexible in what sense? QGIS is still GPL as is anything made with it.

Comment: Ok so I don't fully understand licensing; my company is looking to make an application based on PyQt4 and QGIS libraries which is included in a commercial service (not selling the application itself, but selling the service which includes the application). I want to avoid any complication where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're "flogging a dead horse" here, with regards to PySide, unless you are willing to do (or fund) some serious QGIS development in this area. I highly doubt [PySide can supplant PyQt4](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt) when using the PyQGIS modules. I don't think the bindings are currently agnostic enough to be used by both. Also, just importing `qgis.core` requires the PyQt4 `sip` utility.

It is certainly possible to make the bindings work with PySide, but no one in the QGIS developer community is actively working on this, or even discussing it.

On the licensing side (*and keeping in mind I am not providing any type of legal advice here*), the compiled Python modules `qgis.core`, `qgis.gui`, etc. are linked to Qt, which can be licensed under LGPL.

However, QGIS and PyQt4 are NOT licensed as LGPL, only GPL. If you are charging **for a service**, *and* all the software you create leveraging PyQGIS/PyQt4 libraries (your app) is also GPL-licensed, open source and freely available, you may be OK. This might also be OK for satisfying the Qt use license. [PySide's extra LGPL licensing](http://qt-project.org/wiki/About-PySide) won't gain you any advantages in this scenario.

To be sure, you should ask the licensing questions directly to [Qt](https://qt-project.org/products/licensing) and [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/license), and on the [QGIS developer mailing list](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html). Since I do not know your exact scenario, I am just guessing. Best to ask the projects directly.

Providing a commercial service based upon these libraries, and even redistributing them, is not unheard of, as is the case with [Boundless](http://boundlessgeo.com/) and other similar entities in the geospatial domain. In fact, it is a sound business plan, if you can ensure the licensing concerns are correctly addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, we will be seeking legal advice, and I had already thought about the situation with companies developing for FOSS who are paid by clients.